# How to solve this " `spawn': Exec format error - bin/rails server -p 3000 (Errno::ENOEXEC)" in Rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to connect my Rails application with React and I'm almost done with the setup but each time I run the `./bin/dev` command, I get the following error.

Please, can anyone help out on this? What is it I haven't done?

```
$ ./bin/dev
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `spawn': Exec format error - 
bin/rails server -p 3000 (Errno::ENOEXEC)
```

```
./bin/dev
Installing foreman...
Fetching foreman-0.87.2.gem
Successfully installed foreman-0.87.2
Parsing documentation for foreman-0.87.2
Installing ri documentation for foreman-0.87.2
Done installing documentation for foreman after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `spawn': Exec format error - bin/rails server -p 3000 (Errno::ENOEXEC)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `block in run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in `chdir'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:367:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_processes'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:364:in `upto'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:364:in `block in spawn_processes'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:363:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:363:in `spawn_processes'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:57:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/cli.rb:42:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/bin/foreman:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `<main>'
```

Profile.dev

[Procfile.dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHa09.png)

Comment: Hi ! Can you check if config/webpack exists pr all node_modules are bundled?

Comment: No, I can't find config/webpack. It's not there. @SarahB

Comment: This seems like a bug somewhere along the call chain. Can you post the full error message (all the lines), or is this single line the only one? In any case, most likely something which should be reported as a bug, is my guess.

Comment: @Casper I thought this has to do with my ruby version and rails. I had to uninstall them and install it again. As soon as i wanted to serve the application using ```.bin/dev```, I had the following errors again: I have updated the question to include the errors I got.

Comment: @Casper I think the error has to do with the ```foreman`` gem that's been installed automatically and I don't know how to work around that.

Comment: ...can you run `bin/rails server` directly?

Comment: @Casper bin/rails server is working perfectly well but because I want to display my App which is my entry point to my javascript. so .bin/dev is what i use except i want to display the Rails application.

Comment: Please post your procfile. My guess is `bin/rails` might have to be replaced with `bin\rails`, or maybe `bin\\rails`. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: @Casper Ok. I have updated my post with the Procfile.dev as requested.

Answer (score 2):

For me removing the 'bin/' from Procfile part worked 
It looked like this

```
web: rails server -p 3000
js: yarn build watch
```

Just the same as i'd run standard rails server

Comment: I ran into this issue today (at the same time github had some strange issue as well).  I removed the bin/ from my profile as well and that DID solve it on my Windows 10 machine as well.

Changed:
FROM: css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch

TO: css: rails tailwindcss:watch